# Is 'hot-wiring' two contacts a proper way to bypass a broken button?

Tags: voltage, power, soldering, hardware, hacking

I have a broken cell phone, and its power button is not working at all.

Examining the device's motherboard I have discovered the button has five pins. As seen on the manufacturer's service manual, the connections look like this:

[image: manual detail]

My theory is that it could be possible to join the four ground pins into one and create an equivalent circuit by placing two wires out of the motherboard: the first coming out from the GND and the second from the positive part of the chip (the one in the right of the picture).

With this setup, would connecting the two wires one to each other bypass the broken button action and simulate a press to power on the device?

Comment: Connecting Vdc to GND probably won't have the effect you're looking for! I assume it's a typo :)  If you can pull a wire from the node connected to the switch's Pin1 and another from GND it should work just fine.

Comment: Edited, I meant pin 1. So there wouldn't be any problem with joining the four grounds? It bugs me the fact that there are two 0Vs zones, instead of one.

Comment: I don't get why you don't just put in another switch

Comment: I have bought some switches, but trying to solder properly a 4mm component into 5 pins made me give up instead of damaging the motherboard.

Comment: Replacing the switch is the "proper" way.  What you suggest will probably work as a short term hack but your flapping loose wires will become an antenna and may make your phone reboot randomly.  Just get a fine pointed soldering iron tip and replace the switch.

Comment: What I want is a temporary solution in order to recover my data. What do you mean by becomming an antenna? Also, I don't know which soldering tip would work better in this situation, nor the materials I'd need.

Comment: Take it to a cellphone repair shop, if all you want is the data. Shouldn't be an astronomical expenditure. Then learn about electronics and practical skills at your leisure, but not on something as finicky as a cellphone motherboard.

Comment: Why are you sure, that it is the power button that is not working and not any other component required for the startup? E.g. the connection to the battery could be broken or maybe a softstart circuit is defective.

Comment: It is a Nexus 5, and I experienced a bootloop; the most common symptom of a broken power button (a really usual issue in this model). I am sure it's the power button's fault. Also, when I connect the device to AC, the battery icon shows as usual on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bypass the switch in the way you suggest.

You would need to temporarily connect the switch's Pin 1 to a GND node.  Any ground connection should work; you don't need to use any of the specific connections soldered to the switch.  Also, no need to connect the grounds together.

On the switch, Pin 1 and Pin 2 get connected when the button is pressed (obviously).  Pins 3, 4, and 5 are connection to the switch's chassis, and are provided to ground out the switch case.  This acts as a shield for EMI.

Be warned: soldering to a cell phone motherboard can be *very* tricky.  It's easy to make it worse instead of better.  Also, as mentioned in the comments, the short wires may act like antennas at cell frequencies.  I expect this won't be a problem, but it could cause strange stuff to happen.

If you decide to proceed, I recommend placing the phone in Airplane Mode as soon as you can.

Comment: Do you suggest connecting to any special ground? Directly to the battery? To the place in the motherboard where pin 2 should be placed?

Comment: @xvlaze I would take it to any available ground on the PCB, but not the battery (although this would probably work, too). Of course, sometimes that's not easy to find.  If the button has a convenient soldering spot on Pin 2, this would be the way to go. If the button is still in place, you could simply hold the wire to the metal chassis (of the button) to bypass the switch.